# ext4 converted/mounted as ext2?

Tags: linux, filesystems, fedora

Can I conver/mount ext4 as ext2? Because I have pendrive flash disk and I heard that ext2 is better than ext4 but my installator forced me to ext4. Can I do something with it?

Comment: What is the real problem? Just format it again as ext2? Just use ext4? In what way would ext2 be "better"?

Comment: ext4 uses journalising, which shorts pendrive life.

Comment: I heard that I don't have to reformat it. Just change the type (?) or mount it as ext2 without losing data.

Answer (score 3):

You can mount ext4 with journalling disabled.

Most people don't seem to think there is a significant problem with journalling on a large flash-memory device.

Comment: For disabling the journal, [see here](http://cptl.org/wp/index.php/2010/03/30/tuning-solid-state-drives-in-linux/)

Comment: isn't there another way without external system ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why those down-voting but this is a valid question, as journalising does shorten pendrive life.

There are two options,

- Just use `ext2` as type in the `fstab` file, and the FS will be mounted as `ext2`, without journalising.
- Or for more permanent solution, `tune2fs` is the tool to disable `ext4` journalising.